# Scala map to Java map conversion

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to convert a map from scala to java:

```
private def toJava(map: Map[Int, Set[Int]]): util.Map[Integer, util.Set[Integer]] = {
    scala.collection.JavaConverters.mapAsJavaMapConverter(
      map.mapValues(scala.collection.JavaConverters.setAsJavaSetConverter(_).asJava)).asJava
}
```

However, the `Int` is not converted to `Integer`, And I don't find the way to achieve that.

What is the scala way to do it?

Comment: `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`        
        
  `private def toJava(map: Map[Int, Set[Int]]): java.util.Map[Integer, java.util.Set[Integer]] =`      
     `mapAsJavaMapConverter(map.mapValues(setAsJavaSetConverter(_).asJava))`     
      `.asJava.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[java.lang.Integer, java.util.Set[Integer]]]`

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate of the referenced question. I think it is SO and scala interest to have more questions that are related.

Comment: @NisseEngström - it is easy to notice that it is not "straight forward" to understand the solution to one question from the other - although they are similar, this one is a bit more complicated (collection inside a collection).

Comment: Someone wants to get answer. Why another one close it as duplicate without clear answer? Is the main goal of website to get answer and to help people?

Comment: @oshai For posterity, You can add correct code to your post with label **Answer**